How to set default command for spring boot shell?
How can I define a default command for a Spring Boot Shell application?
Right now I have to enter java -jar app.jar calculate-cognitive-metrics ".\\src\\main\\java\\"
I want to change this to java -jar app.jar ".\\src\\main\\java\\" so that it executes this command by default.
Also, when I try to just run java -jar app.jar --help I get this org.springframework.shell.CommandNotFound: No command found for '--help' instead of the help output. I'm new to Java and Spring Shell and I've already checked the docs, but I don't really get how to configure it properly to do what I want.
CognitiveAnalysisApplication.java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CognitiveAnalysisApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CognitiveAnalysisApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(final ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
  }
}

ShellCommands.java (excerpt)
  @ShellMethod(key = "calculate-cognitive-metrics")
  public void calculateCognitiveMetrics(
      final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "src/main/java") String directoryPath,
      final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "", value = "--html-report") String htmlReport,
      final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "", value = "--csv-report") String csvReport,
      final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "", value = "--json-report") String jsonReport
  ) throws IOException {


Use this command in the terminal:
java -jar app.jar calculate-cognitive-metrics --help

Example code:
@SpringBootApplication
@ShellComponent
public class DemoShellApplication {

    @ShellMethod(key = "calculate-cognitive-metrics")
    public void calculateCognitiveMetrics(
            final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "src/main/java") String directoryPath,
            final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "", value = "--html-report") String htmlReport,
            final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "", value = "--csv-report") String csvReport,
            final @ShellOption(defaultValue = "", value = "--json-report") String jsonReport
    ) throws IOException {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoShellApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Output from my local:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.3)

2024-09-13T09:01:56.437+05:30  INFO 28814 --- [demo-shell] [           main] com.example.DemoShellApplication         : Starting DemoShellApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 21.0.1 with PID 28814 (/Users/anish/demo-shell-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by anish in /Users/anish)
2024-09-13T09:01:56.440+05:30  INFO 28814 --- [demo-shell] [           main] com.example.DemoShellApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-09-13T09:01:57.545+05:30  INFO 28814 --- [demo-shell] [           main] com.example.DemoShellApplication         : Started DemoShellApplication in 1.582 seconds (process running for 2.192)
NAME
       calculate-cognitive-metrics -

SYNOPSIS
       calculate-cognitive-metrics --directoryPath String --html-report String --csv-report String --json-report String --help

OPTIONS
       --directoryPath String
       [Optional, default = src/main/java]

       --html-report String
       [Optional]

       --csv-report String
       [Optional]

       --json-report String
       [Optional]

       --help or -h
       help for calculate-cognitive-metrics
       [Optional]


Hey, thank you for your answer, but this isn't really working for me. I'm getting No command found for '--help' when I try --help and @Shelloption is the legacy annotation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/reference/options/basics/legacyannotation.html), I've tried it as well, but also without much success. You can see the whole source here https://github.com/floriankraemer/cognitive-code-analysis-java
